# bad character U+002D '-' in my helm template

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

This is my template yaml file:

```
   containerPolicies:
      - containerName: "prometheus-{{ .Release.Name }}-prometheus"
        {{- if index .Values "prometheus-operator" "prometheus" "verticalPodAutoscaler" "containerPolicies" "minAllowed" }} 
        minAllowed:
          memory: {{ .Values.prometheus-operator.prometheus.verticalPodAutoscaler.containerPolicies.minAllowed.memory | default "2Gi" | quote }}
          cpu: {{ .Values.prometheus-operator.prometheus.verticalPodAutoscaler.containerPolicies.minAllowed.cpu | default "500m" | quote }}
        {{- end }}
```

This is my stacktrace:

> [ERROR] templates/: parse error at (xxx-xx-xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx.yaml:23):
> bad character U+002D '-' Error: 1 chart(s) linted, 1 chart(s) failed

Any idea ?

Comment: You can't use `.Values.prometheus-operator`; you need `index .Values "prometheus-operator"`.  Also consider renaming the configuration key to camelCase so that `.Values.prometheusOperator` works.